# Как в Excel подставить значение?

Tags: excel

Доброго всем дня.
Как в Excel подставить текстовое значение к результату формулы?
Допустим, формула "=2+2".
Как сюда подставить, например, "шт."?
Аналогично как в программировании (конкатенацией или присоединением), есть такая возможность у Excel?  
Что-то типа:

> "=2+2.'(шт.)'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю возможно ли сложить формулу и текст, но 100% можно объединить значение другой ячейки + текст. Проверить сейчас возможности нет.
Посмотрите на функции СЦЕПИТЬ и ТЕКСТ, а также оператор & (амперсанд).
Подробнее на  [оф. сайте](http://office.microsoft.com/ru-ru/excel-help/HP010062736.aspx#BMcombine_text_and_numbers_from_differe)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно **сцепить формулу и текст** или показать работающую формулу, то не так все просто.

Например: в B1 формула "=A1+A2".

Хотим видеть в C1:
"A1+A2=5 шт."

Вариант, который предложил undestroyer, для сцепки в формуле1 формулы2 и другого текста работает, если:

- формулу2 вписывать в формулу1 вручную (применимо, если формул одна-две);
- ячейке задать текстовый формат и вписать туда  формулу2, но саму работающую формулу2 разместить в другой ячейке.

Но если нужно  отображать не одну - несколько (десятков) формул?

В этом случае нужно писать макрос. Но есть и другой вариант, проще.

**Макрофункции.**

Такие функции непосредственно на листе *Excel* не работают, для работы макрофункций использование макросов должно быть разрешено.

В *Excel* есть еще один неплохой инструмент – именованные диапазоны. Пробуем?

Выделить ячейку для вставки формулы со сцепкой (у нас это *C1*). Нажать *Ctrl+F3* – откроется окно для работы с именами. Вписать имя (пусть будет "хочу_формулу"), в поле *Диапазон* вписать формулу:

`=ПОЛУЧИТЬ.ЯЧЕЙКУ(6;Лист1!B1)`

(ссылку можно не писать вручную – клик на ячейке, но не забыть убрать закрепление ссылки (знаки $), ведь формулу хотим размножить, чтобы видеть и другие работающие формулы)

*ОК-Закрыть* – имеем именованный диапазон.

Если в *C1* вписать простую формулу *=хочу_формулу*, в ней отобразится формула, работающая в ячейке *B1*.

Чтобы сцепить формулу и ее результат, применим сцепление (конкатенацию) текста, предварительно удалив знак «=» из формулы:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(хочу_формулу;"=";;1)&"="&B1&" шт."
```

*ПОДСТАВИТЬ(где;что_менять;на_что_менять; вхождение)*. Единичка в функции - заменить только первый знак "=", без этого параметра из формулы будут удалены все "=".

Comment: Сколько много букв и, конечно же, не плохих знаний MS Excel.  
Но мне, как оказалось, всего лишь требовалось:  
> =2+2 &" шт."

Comment: Я понял, что автору темы нужно было сцепить результат и единицу измерения.
А "много букв" - это ответ на замечание-догадку undestroyer'а
"возможно ли сложить формулу и текст"

Не думаю, что ответ чем-то может помешать в данной теме.

Answer (score 0):

> Как сюда подставить, например, "шт."?

Применить ***Пользовательские форматы*** MS Excel либо интерактивно или в коде макроса.

1. Интерактивно:
   1.1. выделяем необходимые ячейки, по правой кнопке мыши, из контекстного меню выбираем пункт **Формат ячеек...**;
   [image: Формат ячеек]
   1.2. Далее **Число** - **(все форматы)** и в поле **Тип** вводим маску ***0,00" шт"***.
   [image: Маска формата]
   1.3. Результат форматирования:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В макросе:
   2.1. Используем свойство ячейки ***NumberFormat***

   ```
      Sub Test_Format()
          For i = 2 To 12   'т.к. первая строка это заголовки
                Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00"" шт"""
          Next
      End Sub
   ```

Кратко по применению пользовательских форматов http://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/9/72/